# Extract icons from EPS file

Tags: bash, console, imagemagick, eps

I've got a grid of icons, stored in EPS file.

There is something like 80 icons in there.

I need to extract them from the file. Is it possible using imagemagick or something like that, without having to drag 'cut' instrument using gimp?

Comment: try this [Extracting icons from a single image](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18970/extracting-icons-from-a-single-image)

Comment: Cyrus, eps itself is kind of under NDA. Letizia, thanks, but I thought that there should be an automatic way.

Comment: Could you specify icons dimension and position in eps file? Did you consider `-crop` [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) options?

Comment: Letizia, Thanks for the answer again:) It seems that mr Fabby was right, writing that auto-way would be no less hussle than handy-way. (need to determine all the positions and sizes) :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do this automatically, *but*  if you have only one file with 80 icons, doing it automatically is going to take more time then doing it manually, so if you're planning on having 100 files of 80 icons each, doing it automatically is going to save you time...

:-(